# Run ANOVA before MANOVA?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, manova

In a mixed design I have two independent variables (IVs) and one dependent variable (DV). The DV can also be interpreted with its sub-dimensions. Thus, the formerly (one) DV can be spitted up into four DVs.

Now my question is: Does it make sense to run a two way mixed ANOVA (two IVs and one DV, which is, Cognitive Absorption --> see below) first, interpret its results etc, and then run a two way mixed MANOVA (two IVs and four DVs, which are, Sub-Dimension 1, Sub-Dimension 2, Sub-Dimension 3, Sub-Dimension 4 --> see below) second? Or should I just run the MANOVA.

Structure of the scale:

- Cognitive Absorption (Overall DV =  16 items)
- ---- Sub-Dimension 1: Concentration (4 items)
- ---- Sub-Dimension 2: Enjoyment (4 items)
- ---- Sub-Dimension 3: Temporal Dissociation (4 items)
- ---- Sub-Dimension 4: XXX (4 items)

Comment: It would help potential respondents if you were to include information illustrative of the DV and its *sub-dimensions*, e.g., a small sample of data. Right now I, for one, have no idea what you're referring to. That said running preliminary ANOVA(s) as a baseline for comparison with more sophisticated downstream models is *always* a good idea and practice.

Comment: Hello DJoonson, I've updated my question to show, how the scale is structured. I hope this helps. Kind regards and many thanks for your reply

Comment: If you haven't answered your question by now it might help to start with first principles: what is the objective of this analysis? What question(s) are your trying to answer? Given that, try to identify an analysis that would address that goal(s). Right now, you're backing into an objective by trying to figure out a methodology...a case of putting the cart before the horse.